# Powershell Quoted variables parameters in a job

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, start-job

```
$buildDef = "Service.xxxx"
$buildDefFull="MyProject/$buildDef"

Start-Job -Name 'Service1' -ScriptBlock { tfsbuild start /collection:"http://yyyy:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"  /builddefinition:"$buildDefFull" }
```

i get this error:

```
Option builddefinition requires a value.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Option builddefinition requires a value.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

i can't seem to get tfsbuild to accept the parameter in a start job... it actually runs fine if i just do the tfsbuild part with no job.

Any ideas how i'm supposed to pass that value?
tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$buildDefFull` variable is outside the scope of the scriptblock.

You  have 2 options:

### PowerShell 3+

Use the `Using` scope modifier:

```powershell
$buildDef = "Service.xxxx"
$buildDefFull="MyProject/$buildDef"

Start-Job -Name 'Service1' -ScriptBlock { tfsbuild start /collection:"http://yyyy:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"  /builddefinition:"$Using:buildDefFull" }
```

### Any Version

Define and pass parameters to the scriptblock:

```powershell
$buildDef = "Service.xxxx"
$buildDefFull="MyProject/$buildDef"

Start-Job -Name 'Service1' -ScriptBlock { param($bdf) tfsbuild start /collection:"http://yyyy:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"  /builddefinition:"$bdf" } -ArgumentList $buildDefFull
```